# Traversing from a mysql table using two loops

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have following table in MySQL

```
|Column1|Column2|Column3|
-------------------------
|Data1  |Data2  |Data3  |
|Data4  |Data5  |Data6  |
|Data7  |Data8  |Data9  |
|Data10 |Data11 |Data12 |
-------------------------
```

Now in this table, I am fetching column names as well all the 12 cells using PHP

here is the loop that I am working on.

```
    for($i=0, $j=0; $i<$loopMax; $i++,$j++){//i run rows, j run columns
    if($j>=$column_count){
             $j=0;
    }
    $columns[$i][$j] = mysql_result($query_exec, $j, 'COLUMN_NAME');
    $response[$i][$columns[$i][$j]] = @$result[$j];
    }
     print_r($response);
```

**$maxLoop** is the value of a number of columns multiplied by the number of rows. that way I get the total number of cells I need to fetch. I have to send this response in a json string so getting this cell values along with its respective column names is important because that's what is going to help the UI end recognize where to put which value.
*there is no primary key to the table*.

What I want to do is, fetch each of this cell value and the column name it belongs to and put it in an array. And send that array as jason string.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: So, vote to close as unclear and move on and let someone else figure it out.

Comment: Why are you structuring your database like that?

Comment: @GordonLinoff edited my question, please read the last paragraph.

Comment: @Lawrence I swear if I had to do it, I would put a primary key in there and just fetch everything based on that. but I can not change it now. The project is live and I have to fetch this way only.

Comment: Your question is unclear. For this question providing for example the version of `MySQL` you use,  could result in having more answers, since from certain versions and above `MySQL` supports natively `JSON` functions which you could use. For example `SELECT JSON_OBJECT('Column1', Column1, 'Column2', Column2...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have `MySQL` version `5.7.8` and above  installed on your server, then you could use native `JSON` functions in your query.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('Column1', `Column1`, 'Column2', `Column2`, 'Column3', `Column3`);
```

The result would be something like...

```
{ "Column1":"Data1", "Column2":"Data2", "Column3":"Data3" },
...
...
{ "Column1":"Data10", "Column2":"Data11", "Column3":"Data12" }
```

Comment: Fantastic +1 and you deserve +1000

Comment: @AmrBerag i am glad this helped. This means that you probably have MySQL version that includes `JSON` functions. Take a better look to all of them https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html i think they will be most helpful for lot of things you might have in mind. I know they worked for me :)

Comment: Can we do the opposite ?, I couldn't find it in docs, there is insert function but it's used in queries result as well.

Comment: @AmrBerag you mean if you can use `JSON_OBJECT` for `INSERT` yes. Example `INSERT INTO mysqltable VALUES  (JSON_OBJECT("TextSample", "Our mascot is a dolphin named \"Sakila\"."));`

Comment: I hope it will be added to MariaDB and that it's injection-proof

Comment: I think soon webpages will be sarved from port 3306 instead of 80

Answer (score 0):

Try making naming rule for your column so you can get the column name like this:

```
 $column_name = 'column'  .'-' .$j
```

and this will work with the current column names without the hyphen like this:

```
 $columns[$i][$j]  = 'column' . $j
```

In other words you just append the value of $j to the word 'column'.

-Edit:
I think you can even calculate the column name in the front end of your application.